# How to access Spring Model object details in javascript function present in the view?

Tags: javascript, spring, model, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot project where I am using thymeleaf as view technology.
In 1 scenario I need to use the model object passed to the view inside a javascript function.
this model object is a map. I am able to access it and I can print it. but I am not able to access its specific values.

[javascript function accessing the model object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSe15.png)

in the output I can see the alert printing the map

[alert printing the model object map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV5pJ.png)

But I am not able to access specific properties of this map. I tried dot operator, square brackets etc.
Can someone please tell how can access all the details of this map in javascript?

Thanks,

I tried following

1. packageMap.pkgId.totalFees.
2. packageMap[pkgId].totalFees.
3. packageMap(pkgId).totalFees.

None of these works.
I want to access the specific properties of the values of the map.